# jquery isolate class with variable name via regular expressions

Tags: jquery

Please note that I don't *know* what the full class I'm wanting to isolate is, only its format, which is for example:

```
class="loadable context-enc encounterTimelineEncounterDateitem"
```

What I'm looking for is context-enc or something that matches:

```
.match(/\bcontext-[a-z]+\b/)
```

and it's really the [a-z]+ part that I want to discover.  I don't want to so much test whether there IS a class in there that matches, but want to know what the string after "context-" is (in this case 'enc').  Something like:

```
function getcontext(class, 'context-'){ .. }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function would likely return what you want...

```
function getContext(className, withString){
    var r = new RegExp("\\b"+ withString +"[a-z]+\\b");
    var s = new RegExp("^"+withString);
    return className.match(r)[0].replace(s,'');
}
```

If you build the regular expression dynamically you can insert your variable content into it, and then to isolate the `[a-z]+` portion just remove the searched for string from the result.

**EDIT:** Using @nathan-taylor's capture group suggestion we can simplify the function to:

```
function getContext(className, withString){
    var r = new RegExp("\\b"+ withString +"([a-z]+)\\b");
    return className.match(r)[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `[a-z+]` in your regex in parentheses to get the value back in a capture group:

`"context-enc".match(/\bcontext-([a-z]+)\b/)`

> ["context-enc", "enc"]

Comment: THANKS! I was torn between voting yours or @Ben_Thielker as the accepted answer - you both answered a part of the question, and now I know how to approach back-references in JS (which I already knew in PHP's preg_match() using the 3rd parameter.